# shell script: `[[` not working as expected

Tags: upstart, dash-shell

I have a script:

```
ENABLE_SYSLOG=true
test -r /etc/default/inotifywait && . /etc/default/inotifywait || exit 99
test -d $INOTIFY_FOLDER || exit 100

inotifywait -mrq -e ATTRIB --format '%w%f' "$INOTIFY_FOLDER" | while IFS= read -r FILE
do
    if [ -f $FILE ];then
        # If file
        if [ `stat -c %a $FILE` != "664" ] ;then
            CHMOD_LOG=$(chmod -v 664 "$FILE")
            [[ "$ENABLE_SYSLOG" = true ]] && logger -t inotifywait -p user.info "$CHMOD_LOG" &
        fi
    else
        # If directory
        if [ `stat -c %a $FILE` != "2775" ] ;then
            CHMOD_LOG=$(chmod -v 2775 "$FILE")
            [[ "$ENABLE_SYSLOG" = true ]] && logger -t inotifywait -p user.info "$CHMOD_LOG" &
        fi
    fi
done
```

Why my condition

```
[[ "$ENABLE_SYSLOG" = true ]] && logger -t inotifywait -p user.info "$CHMOD_LOG"
```

Not work ?

If I remove

```
[[ "$ENABLE_SYSLOG" = true ]] &&
```

Then everything is fine.

I try to remove ampersand (&), try other condition (as you can see in example), try if instead of [[ - but all in vain.

Any condition is not work

Comment: You can just say: `"$ENABLE_SYSLOG" && ...`

Comment: While this may seem clever, it's probably not a good idea. You should try to find out why your attempt does not work, since it should. What version of `bash` are you using? How do you run the script?

Comment: I ran a script via upstart job(script ... end script) in ubuntu 12.04 (bash version 4.2.25(1)). May be upstart does not use bash(use dash or sh instead)?

Comment: if your problem is solved, please, either delete the question or post an answer and accept it after 48 hrs. Good luck to all.

Comment: Ubuntu indeed uses `dash`, not `bash`, for system scripts, so `[[` is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

`[[ ... ]]` is present in most advanced shells (`ksh`, `bash`, and `zsh`) but is missing in POSIX `sh` and in Ubuntu `/bin/sh` (which is a symlink to `/bin/dash`).

You can either replace `[[ ... ]]` with `[ ... ]` or `test ...` (both are equivalent, the second makes it clear that `test` is a command while `[ ... ]` appears as if it is special syntax), or (unless the script is explicitly invoked as `sh FILENAME`), start it with `#!/bin/bash`. Note that `[[ ... ]]` is parsed differently than `test` or `[ ... ]`, as `[[` is a reserved word, while `[` and `test` are merely builtin commands. Specifically, field splitting and globbing are not done between `[[` and `]]`, while `=` and `==` in this context do shell pattern matching if neither string is quoted. Furthermore, the `=~` operator to do regexp matching is not present in `test` or `[`.